# Printing a shell variable yields empty output

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution

I have the following program where I want to print a variable `$var` that I fill with the execution time of a program. However, when outputting it to the console with `echo` or `printf` the value is empty.

**Program:**

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for n in 1 2 3 4;
    do my_time="$(time var=$(echo "scale=100; 4*a(1)" | bc -l))";
    
    echo $var
    echo $my_time       
    printf "Value of PI is :%s\n" $var
done
```

**Output:**

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s


Value of PI is :

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s


Value of PI is :

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s


Value of PI is :

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s


Value of PI is :
```

Where is the problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command substitution `$(...)` runs the commands in a subshell. Setting a variable in a subshell isn't propagated to the parent shell.

In this case, it's even more problematic, as the `time` builtin doesn't output to the standard output or error. In order to be able to capture its output, you need to run it in a subshell and capture that shell's stderr - but that way, you can't set any variable.

The only possible way I see is to run the command twice, once capturing the output and once capturing the time:

```
    var=$(bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)')
    my_time=$( (time bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)') 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

Or, capture both the details at the same time and separate them later:

```
    out=$( (time bc -l <<< 'scale=100; 4*a(1)') 2>&1)
    var=${out%real*}
    my_time=real${out#*real}
```

Comment: Hi Choroba, Thanks for your quick response. I changed the code but now it gives me error:

CODE:


    do var=$(echo "scale=100; 4*a(1)" | bc -l)
    my_time=time($var)
    echo $var
    echo $my_time       
    printf "Value of PI is :%s\n" $var





OUTPUT:


pi2.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: What error? Also, check the update.

Comment: Edited my previous comment  but I just saw your edited answer. Will try that code, thanks a tom

Comment: That's not what I posted.

Comment: I run it using bash/ sh commands or using ./

Comment: Sorry for that, I missed your edited post. Now trying what you posted.

Comment: Using `sh` might be problematic if you're using bashisms.

Comment: Sure Chorba, I wont use sh. Thanks for your input,it worked

Comment: Can you please help me with one last thing, my output shows 2 lines of print, how can I fix it?

Comment: Value of PI is :3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307\
Value of PI is :8164062862089986280348253421170676
Time calculated is :real
Time calculated is :0m0.008s
Time calculated is :user
Time calculated is :0m0.004s
Time calculated is :sys
Time calculated is :0m0.000s

Comment: Post a new question to ask a new question. You might add a link to the older one for context.